# How to transpose a 2 Element Vector

Tags: python, numpy, transpose

In python, I have a 2x1 array

```
a=array([[ 0,  4,  8, 12, 16],
     [ 0,  8, 16, 24, 32]])
```

When I extract a column vector

```
c=a[:,1]
```

C becomes a 1x2 array, and I wish it to be a 2x1 array. Applying transpose does not seems to do the trick.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example of the output you want? I'm confused: do you want to have 2 arrays of 1 element each?

Comment: In numpy, your array is 2 x 5, isn't it? And am I understanding that you want to extract a column slice as a column matrix, rather than a vector?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After

```
c=a[:,1]
```

`c` is now:

```
array([4, 8])
```

i.e. a 1D array (so even not 1x2).

If you want it a 2x1 array, try this:

```
c = a[:,1:2]
```

it will become:

```
array([[4],
       [8]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `c.reshape(2,1)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Other options include:

```
import numpy as np
c = a[:,1]
```

and then access the data with the desired shape using:

```
c[:,np.newaxis]
```

or

```
c[:,None]
```